# Different Discounts for Different Quantities

Tags: magento-1.8, shopping-cart-price-rules, tierprice

What would be the step by step to make it so certain sku's are 5% for quantities 2-4, 10% for quantities of 5-8?

I've tried 'contains', 'is one of', 'is' 2,3,4

If I only have 1 in cart, it gives the 5%

If I have 5 it isn't 'bumping' up to the 10% but instead continuing with 5% for all 5 instead of 10% for all 5 in cart

Answer (score 1):

We suggest you to create 2 shopping price rules. For your 5/10% example:

Rule 1

[image]

and Rule 2

[image]

If such value as SKU is missing in your conditions dropdown, you'll need to enable it in the attribute settings:

Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> SKU -> Frontend Properties -> Use for Promo Rule Conditions -> Yes

Comment: I have it exactly as the above (my sku's being different of course). The product is configurable... if I have 2 or more in the cart of the same option, the above 'almost' works. If I have 2 or more in the cart that are different selected options, the above does not work at all.

Comment: I found out that when you use 2 quantity in cart with equals or less/greater than conditions in one condition combination only equals or greater condition works. But I tried 2 rules with is one of condition and it works. Make sure that Stop Further Rules Processing is equal to No and you use SKU of configurable product but not Associated product's SKU.

Comment: Could that be the thing that is causing havoc in that I'm adding all the sku's of all the assoicated products?

Comment: Ok, the above works... but think I've asked this before or it was sort of implied in that the product has 2 options, 1 has 2 choices, the other has 63  (so 63 x 2 = 126 associated products )

If a customer adds 2,3,4 of 1 associated product to the shopping cart the rule works. However, if a customer adds 1 of the associated sku's and adds a different one, that makes 2 in the cart and the rule doesn't work.

Comment: Cannot use 'Quantity in cart equals or less than 4' because 1 would be included...

I use 'Quantity in cart is one of 2,3,4'